# Combine iOS Custom Subject not emitting values

Tags: ios, combine

In the following code I am trying to create a custom subject that can emit only even numbers. For some reason It is not emitting any values. I was using CurrentValueSubject before but that was picking the last value. I want to emit any value as long as it is even number.

```
class EvenSubject<Failure: Error>: Subject {
    
    typealias Output = Int
    
    private let wrapped: PassthroughSubject<Int, Failure>
    
    init(initialValue: Int) {
        self.wrapped = PassthroughSubject()
        let evenInitialValue = EvenSubject.isEven(value: initialValue) ? initialValue: 0
        send(evenInitialValue)
    }
    
    private static func isEven(value: Int) -> Bool {
        value % 2 == 0
    }
    
    func send(_ value: Output) {
        print("send")
        
        if value % 2 == 0 {
            wrapped.send(value)
        }
        
    }
    
    func send(completion: Subscribers.Completion<Failure>) {
        print("send completion")
        wrapped.send(completion: completion)
    }
    
    func send(subscription: Subscription) {
        print("send subscription")
        wrapped.send(subscription: subscription)
    }
    
    func receive<S>(subscriber: S) where S : Subscriber, Failure == S.Failure, Output == S.Input {
        wrapped.receive(subscriber: subscriber)
    }
    
}


let subject = EvenSubject<Never>(initialValue: 4)

subject.send(10)
subject.send(7)
subject.send(14)


let cancellable = subject.sink { _ in
    
} receiveValue: { value in
    print(value)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In here you are sending values and then subscribing to it.

```
let subject = EvenSubject<Never>(initialValue: 4)

subject.send(10)
subject.send(7)
subject.send(14)


let cancellable = subject.sink { _ in
    
} receiveValue: { value in
    print(value)
}
```

If you change the order:

```
let subject = EvenSubject<Never>(initialValue: 4)

let cancellable = subject.sink { _ in
    
} receiveValue: { value in
    print(value)
}

subject.send(10)
subject.send(7)
subject.send(14)
```

You'll see the output:
10
14

Comment: Thanks for some reason it never calls the sink for the initialValue. Should that be fired if the number is even?

Answer (score 0):

Your question proposes an excellent exercise, but if anyone is interested in something practical, you can use this:

```
[10, 7, 14]
    .publisher
    .filter { $0 % 2 == 0 }
    .sink(receiveCompletion: { print("Completed with: \($0)") },
        receiveValue: { print($0) })
    .store(in: &subscriptions)

output:
// 10
// 14
// Completed with: finished
```